# How to export an xtable as PDF directly via R script?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, xtable

I have a `data.frame` that I need as a nice PDF table for a scientific poster. While it's very easy to export plots via `pdf()`, I'm stuck with this table.

I know how to get a PDF table with rmarkdown, e.g.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r tab, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
xtable(head(mtcars))
```
````

But I want this output **directly** from the R script, e.g.

```
renderThisToPDF(xtable(head(mtcars), to="nicetable.pdf")  # fantasy code
```

How would I do this?

So far I attempted this code with a indirection via `writeLines`

````
code <- "library(xtable)\nprint(xtable(head(mtcars)))"

fileConn <- file("output.Rmd")
writeLines(cat("---\noutput: pdf_document\n---\n```{r tab, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}\n", 
               code, "\n```\n"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)

knitr::knit('output.Rmd')
````

but failed with an error.

````
Error in writeLines(cat("---\noutput: pdf_document\n---\n```{r tab, echo=FALSE,
                        results='asis'}\n",  : 
                          can only write character objects
````

I guess there's probably an easier solution?

Comment: *Why* do you want to render it directly? What’s the problem with the knitr workflow? I’m asking because you’ll probably have more luck fixing those issues in your current workflow and automating the knitting than with producing good-looking tables via e.g. table grobs.

Comment: It is more of a desperate act. I don't have a problem with the knitr workflow, I just want to avoid to work on a separate `.Rmd` file manually. I know there's a `file` option in `print.xtable` where we can save a table as `.tex` file. I wouldn't either know the way though to automate the knitting process. May I assume that you know the solution I have in mind?

Comment: Indeed, just use `rmarkdown::render` on your whole document (or parts). This will produce a PDF without any manual work needed. Regarding your specific code, the issue is the `writeLines(cat` part. It’s not clear what your thought process was but `writeLines` and `cat` are essentially alternatives that perform the same (or similar) function. You’d use either of them, not nest both. You might have meant to use `c` instead of `cat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility, without `rmarkdown`.

```
library(xtable)
latex <- print.xtable(xtable(head(iris)), print.results = FALSE)

writeLines(
  c(
    "\\documentclass[12pt]{article}",
    "\\begin{document}",
    "\\thispagestyle{empty}",
    latex,
    "\\end{document}"
  ),
  "table.tex"
)

tools::texi2pdf("table.tex", clean = TRUE)
```

Or, using the `standalone` document class:

```
latex <- print.xtable(xtable(head(iris)), print.results = FALSE, 
                      floating = FALSE)
writeLines(
  c(
    "\\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}",
    "\\usepackage{caption}",
    "\\begin{document}",
    "\\minipage{\\textwidth}",
    latex,
    "\\captionof{table}{My caption}",
    "\\endminipage",
    "\\end{document}"
  ),
  "table.tex"
)
tools::texi2pdf("table.tex", clean = TRUE)
```

Comment: To avoid an `inputenc` error we need to add `"\\UseRawInputEncoding"` into the `writeLines` part [as suggested on TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429194/136969).

Comment: Is there a way so set an output path in `tools::texi2pdf`?

Answer (score 1):

One Solution would be to use `tableGrob` from `gridExtra`, add the table to a grid plot and save it with `ggsave`

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

ds <- iris[1:10, ]
tg <- tableGrob(ds)
ggsave("test.pdf", tg)
```

This is quite simple but will be less convinient than a LaTeX solution for more complex tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using the `huxtable` package (disclaimer: I am the author)

```
huxtable::quick_pdf(iris[1:10, ])
```

It will automatically open the PDF in your viewer – you can disable this with `auto_open=FALSE`.

For prettier formatting, create a huxtable object:

```
library(huxtable)
ht <- as_hux(iris[1:10, ])
bold(ht)[1,] <- TRUE       # or whatever else you feel like doing
quick_pdf(ht)
```

Comment: Thanks, throws me `incomplete final line found on 'file2ca4496620b8.log'`, though.