# how to see xtable results directly to latex

Tags: r, latex

I have something like this in my R environment

```
myoutput <-  xtable(mtcars)
```

and i want to see the updated `myoutput` in latex automatically, is this possible?

many thanks in advance,

Comment: not clear about the question,  Can't you run the script.  Perhaps you can write a markdown file with the code

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see it rendered rather than as latex code?

Comment: Do you need to ssave as a tex `print(myoutput, file = 'file.tex')`

Comment: this may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607205/how-to-export-an-xtable-as-pdf-directly-via-r-script?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `texPreview` package.

```
library(xtable)
library(texPreview)

LaTeX <- xtable(mtcars)
tex_preview(LaTeX)
```

This code displays the LaTeX table in the RStudio viewer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `somefile.rmd` (or just create one in `R Studio` with this - `.rmd` - extension) then try the following:

````
---
title: "Somefile"
subtitle: "Somefile subtitle"
author: "Your Name"
output:
   beamer_presentation:
      slide_level: 2
      pandoc_args: "--latex-engine=xelatex"
      fig_width: 5
      fig_height: 5
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tikz, graphicx, multirow, colortbl, schemabloc}
- \usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
- ... # something else
---



## Overview of someproject
```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.align = "center", ...}

d <-
    read.csv2("somefile.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".") %>%
    head(.)
````

Using this code you do the following:

1. You create a beamer presentation (smth like `ppt`)
2. In the section between `--- ... ---` you set your `"global configuration"` of the presentation
3. Using `##` you create a new slide
4. Using `{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, ...}` you can insert `R code` that will appear on that slide.