# how to display and export latex data, using kable

Tags: r

I´m trying to make diagram in latex style using this guide: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

```
library(kableExtra)
dt<-mtcars
kable(dt,"latex)
```

Which generates data like:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\hline
  & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb & X\\
\hline
Mazda RX4 & 21.0 & 6 & 160.0 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.620 & 16.46 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4 & -1\\
\hline
Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.0 & 6 & 160.0 & 110 & 3.90 & 2.875 & 17.02 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4 & -1\\
\hline
Datsun 710 & 22.8 & 4 & 108.0 & 93 & 3.85 & 2.320 & 18.61 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
Hornet 4 Drive & 21.4 & 6 & 258.0 & 110 & 3.08 & 3.215 & 19.44 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
Hornet Sportabout & 18.7 & 8 & 360.0 & 175 & 3.15 & 3.440 & 17.02 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 0\\
\hline
Valiant & 18.1 & 6 & 225.0 & 105 & 2.76 & 3.460 & 20.22 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
Duster 360 & 14.3 & 8 & 360.0 & 245 & 3.21 &
```

How can I view the diagram and why cant I see it in the "Viewer" Should I use R Markdown or is there another simpler way? My goal is to export this diagram as .SVG or .PDF file.

Comment: normally rmarkdown or sweave would be used but this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159750/how-to-see-xtable-results-directly-to-latex) show another way if using rstudio

Comment: look up `?rmarkdown::render`

Comment: Are you looking for `View(dt)`? `kable(dt, "latex")` is only for printing `dt` in tabular form in LaTeX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to see xtable results directly to latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159750/how-to-see-xtable-results-directly-to-latex)